# Possible to have multiple gateways on a CentOS 7 server with one interface?

Tags: routing, centos7, gateway

I have a CentOS 7 VM that has a single interface that needs to reach a set of destination IP addresses.

There are two gateway routing devices that can reach this set of IPs in different ways (one via VPN, the other via some direct route).

The CentOS is on the same subnet as these routing devices.

Is it possible to have the CentOS configured to switch between the gateway routing devices for these IPs?

Comment: What do you mean by switching?

Comment: By switching I mean I would like for the packet flow to switch from to a gateway if one is not returning replies.
Poor choice of words I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the functionality, what you want (switching between various gateways by periodic checkings with various probe methods), isn't included into any standard packages. In the cisco this feature is named the **IP SLA**. You can google it to find many scripts those implement similar functionality in the Linux.